# Is it possible to make two files to merge into 1 file (either symlink or whatever)

Tags: windows, file-management, symbolic-link, merge

Let say, i have:

```
c:\A.txt
c:\B.txt
```

I want their content to be mirrored in 1 file in i.e.:

```
d:\combined.txt
```

So, if  `A` or `B` contents updated, that combined contents should be updated too automatically.

How can it be done? ( if possible, I prefer with available built-in Windows features, if not possible, an external tool will be also helpful)

Answer (score 1):

> How can it be done? (I prefer without complex 3-rd party softwares and automatization programs, if possible)

It cannot be done within those requirements. There is no built-in Windows function that would transparently combine file or folder contents in this way.

Comment: ok, and any 3rd party?